# Invariant Violation:Element type is invalid

Tags: react-native, expo

This is the error I am facing

[image: this is the error i am facing]

Can anyone please help me to solve it. I am stuck here and unable to solve it this is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import IndexScreen from './scr/screens/IndexScreen'
import {BlogProvider} from './scr/context/BlogContext';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Index: IndexScreen
   
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Index',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'App'
    }
  }
);

const App =createAppContainer(navigator);
export default()=>{ 
  return(<BlogProvider>
 <App/></BlogProvider>)}
```

```html
and BlogContext code 

import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const BlogContext = React.createContext();
export const BlopProvider= ({Children})=>{
return <BlogContext.Provider>{Children}</BlogContext.Provider>

};
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the importing line,

```
import `react-native-gesture-handler`;
```